# Loading certain amount of elements to each container

Tags: javascript

How can I set the loop to have 10 `.alert` class inside each `.content` class?

```
    var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
for (i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) { 
    $('.contents').append(' <div class="content"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert '+i+'</div></div>')
}
```

Apparently I am loading one `alert` to each `content`

```js
var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
for (i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {
  $('.contents').append(' <div class="content"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + i + '</div></div>')
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: **pseudocode** `<div .content> <div .alert> * 10 </div></div> * ranNumber` Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it like this, this way you can show all the elements in groups of 10

```js
var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var contents = $('.contents');
var element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++, j++) {      
  element.append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + i + '</div>');
  if (j == 9) {
    contents.append(element);
    element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
    j = -1;
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what's the significance of generating a random number but you can introduce an inner loop which loops 10 times and appends an `alert` to the `content` div.

```js
var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

for (i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {
  var element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
  
  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    element.append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + j + '</div>');
  }
  
  $('.contents').append(element);
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks 31piy, this almost what I need but it is not adding the Content from random! I mean when I try ti pass `i` in the second loop for indexing the number of alert I am only getting 0-9 in all contents but it should be 10-19 in second and so on